# How to increment a numeric value using SET /A inside nested FOR in Windows Command Prompt batch file?

Tags: windows, cmd, command-prompt, windows-console

This is my batch script:

```
set vc11path=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC
set path=%path%;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE
set path=%path%;%vc11path%\bin
set path=%path%;G:\ida61\flair61\bin\win
set /a "count = 1"

cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\lib"
c:
for %%i IN (*.lib) DO (
 md a:\libs\%%i.fdr
)

for %%i IN (*.lib) DO (
    for /F "skip=3" %%j in ('link.exe -lib /list %%i') do (
        link.exe -lib /extract:%%j "%vc11path%\lib\%%i" /OUT:"a:\libs\%%i.fdr\%%~nj.n%count%.obj"
        set /a "count+=1"
    )
)

FOR /D %%i IN ("a:\libs\*.fdr") DO for %%j in (%%i\*.obj) do pcf.exe -g0 "%%i\%%~nj.obj"

FOR /D %%i IN ("a:\libs\*.fdr") DO sigmake %%i\*.pat a:\libs\%%~ni.sig
```

I'm trying to increment `count` value using `set /a "count+=1"` in inner loop, but it seems that this command has no effect to increment that variable.

Sorry for my poor English.

Comment: please see http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/40896-using-set-a-statements-in-windows-batch-file/

Comment: Thanks for the link, I used `cmd /v` to run my batch file and it solved the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to enable delayed expansion if you want variables expanded at runtime. Add this line at the beginning of your script:

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
```

and replace `%count%` inside loops and conditionals with `!count!`.